# Using angular ui.layout in column mode - how to create a bottom aligned element

Tags: css, angularjs, border-layout

I just started to use [angular ui-layout](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout) to allow splitting panes in a UI.

I'm trying to create a sidebar that has this blue element on the bottom

[image: sidebar UI]

Is there a way to trick the ui-layout directive to achieve this? I tried doing `size`, but that just does absolute sizing, I want the bluebox just take up some space (showing 100% of its content) and the element above it needs to scroll and take up the rest of the vertical space.

EDIT: added the HTML

```
<ui-layout options="{ flow: 'row' }">
    <div ui-layout-container> top part </div>
    <div ui-layout-container> blue box</div>
</ui-layout>
```

Comment: @Alexander - I added the HTML, but it's kind of pointless because I don't know how to do what I need, so it just shows two panes in row mode :)

Comment: Isn't this just changing the `flow` to `column` as opposed to `row`?  I'm confused, as that should achieve the vertical layout you're after.

Comment: @JoshBurgess - I see I made a complete mess and confused row/column - I know how to put one on top of the other, but I don't know how to make the small box take up only the size it needs

Comment: Then you should only need to give it a `style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"` rule or something to that effect.  Obviously, put it in CSS as opposed to inline style if you can.

Comment: Still are you looking for answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use ui.layout, but I would not recommend to use it to achieve what you want.

ui.layout uses flex box model and you can use it by yourself without using another invasive javascript layout. You can fully achieve what you want using css only.

This is what I did to achieve what you want only using CSS. http://plnkr.co/edit/0mSxkNC5wl6WTbWc81z6?p=preview.

```
<div class="container flex flex-column">
  <div class="top flex flex-row flex-auto flex-stretch">
    <div class="flex-auto">Top</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  </div>
  <div style="background:blue">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

If you are very interested in using Flex layout, I would recommend to use [Angular Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/), and it is advanced and makes more sense than ui.layout.

To know more about flex box, you can see this example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/lxx7QCwZbeZyyUtwiCym?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to learn about flexbox. I hope I can get away with IE10+ support only. Any solutions for 8+ maybe?

Comment: There is a flexbox polyfill called flexie.js. It only works with one of the older syntaxes, and not the new syntax. For more info., http://www.planningforaliens.com/blog/2014/03/11/real-world-flexbox/

Comment: thanks, great link that shows a lot of approaches, I really hope they apply to vertical problems as well, because they seem to be concentrating on horizontal. But I think it's going to be enough to get me going. Thanks

Comment: One reason to use `ui-layout` rather than write own `flex` style is that it provides splitter. You can click on the splitter bar to enlarge or even maximize a div.